# Square version of \cdot (small black square)?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath

I'm looking for the symbol that's similar to \cdot in math mode, but instead of a small circle, it's a square. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: @RomainPicot Have you tried whether this symbol exists anywhere? ...

Comment: I would use `\sqbullet` from [`mathabx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathabx) using [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764).

Comment: Have you seen that symbol in literature? What does it mean?

Comment: @moose The picture is from the book Algebraic Topology by Allen Hatcher. The symbol indicates product path

Answer (score 17):

There are several ways for doing this. One idea could be `\centerdot` from `amssymb`, but this has the defect of sitting on the baseline, despite its name.

One can fix this by observing that the apparent height of the glyph is three times the real height. So smashing the height to one third and using `\vcenter` will raise the symbol up to the formula axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sqcdot}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\morphic@sqcdot\relax}}
\newcommand{\morphic@sqcdot}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\centerdot$}%
  \ht\z@=.33333\ht\z@
  \vcenter{\box\z@}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\bar{f} \sqcdot f\simeq c_{a\sqcdot b}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Second way: import `\sqbullet` from the `mathabx` fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11.5> mathb10
  <11.5-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqcdot}{\mathbin}{mathb}{"0D}% name to be checked

\begin{document}

$\bar{f} \sqcdot f\simeq c_{a\sqcdot b}$

\end{document}
```

One could avoid wasting a symbol font with the help of `\text`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11.5> mathb10
  <11.5-> mathbb12
}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sqcdot}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\usefont{U}{mathb}{m}{n}\symbol{"0D}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\bar{f} \sqcdot f\simeq c_{a\sqcdot b}$

\end{document}
```

Both examples typeset the same

[image]

For using the glyph in the MnSymbol font, it is similar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolC}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> MnSymbolC5
  <5.5-6.5> MnSymbolC6
  <6.5-7.5> MnSymbolC7
  <7.5-8.5> MnSymbolC8
  <8.5-9.5> MnSymbolC9
  <9.5-11.5> MnSymbolC10
  <11.5-> MnSymbolCb12
}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sqcdot}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}\symbol{"69}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\bar{f} \sqcdot f\simeq c_{a\sqcdot b}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Take your pick.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. You may want to check the name `mathbb12`... I eventually ran into compile errors, which I resolved by changing it to `mathb12` (only one `b`).

Comment: Great answer! Is there a simple way to modify it for an unfilled square rather than a filled square? Simply using `\square` is not good enough, since I need the square to be the same size as `\bullet` and `\textopenbullet`, whereas `\square` is too big.

Comment: @EvanAad That's a whole new question.

Answer (score 16):

Handcraft it.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand*\sq{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{.3ex}{.3ex}}}}}

\begin{document}

$f$ by $\bar f$ gives $\bar f \sq f \simeq c$ for $c$ the constant\dots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it the case that this does not automatically handle different math styles (e.g., `\scriptstyle`, etc.)?

Comment: It looks good for me in different styles, but you could, as always, develop some `\mathpalette\sqaux\relax` then `\if\scriptstyle#1.2ex\else\if\scriptscriptstyle#1.15ex\else.3ex\fi\fi` (or whatever dimensions you choose) in place of the dimensions of `\rule`.

Answer (score 12):

Here, I use a `\scalerel*` to make a strutted rule scale to the size of `\cdot`.  `scalerel` package macros work in all math styles automatically (unless disabled).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\sq{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\strut\rule{1ex}{1ex}}{\cdot}}}
\begin{document}
$f$ by $\bar f$ gives $\bar f \sq f \simeq c$ for $c$ the constant\dots\par
$\scriptscriptstyle\bar f \sq f \simeq c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the size/vertical position of the `\rule` allows any size/position of box to be made.  Here, I double the size of the square dot by using `\rule[-.5ex]{2ex}{2ex}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\sq{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\strut\rule[-.5ex]{2ex}{2ex}}{\cdot}}}
\begin{document}
$f$ by $\bar f$ gives $\bar f \sq f \simeq c$ for $c$ the constant\dots\par
$\scriptscriptstyle\bar f \sq f \simeq c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a simple way to modify your answer to obtain an unfilled square rather than a filled square?

Comment: @EvanAad You could adapt this answer, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459167/typesetting-dalembertian-symbol/459179#459179, except changing the scale from that of `\Delta` to instead the scale of `\cdot`.

Answer (score 6):

`\sqbullet` from `mathabx` perhaps?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

 $f \sqbullet f$
\end{document}
```

Comment: With the usual *caveat* that loading `mathabx` changes *all* symbols.

Comment: @egreg: Is `\filledsquare` from `MnSymbol` better?

Comment: No: while `mathabx` symbols somewhat match CM ones, those in MnSymbol are very distinct from them. There's a canonical answer about “importing a single symbol”, though.

Answer (score 6):

Use `\amssymb` package and `\centerdot`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\bar{f} \centerdot f\simeq c$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it sits on the baseline, rather than be vertically centered to the formula axis.

Comment: @egreg, `\mathord{\raisebox{1pt}{$\centerdot$}}` is useful?

Comment: No, it would not work in different font sizes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use direct `\vrule` with `\mathchoice` TeX primitive.

```
\newcount\stylenum  \newdimen\styledim 
\def\varstyle#1{\mathchoice{\stylenum=0 #1}{\stylenum=1 #1}{\stylenum=2 #1}{\stylenum=3 #1}}
\def\mathaxis{\fontdimen22\ifcase\stylenum 
   \textfont\or\textfont\or\scriptfont\or\scriptscriptfont\fi2 }
\def\setstyledim{\styledim=\ifcase\stylenum .1em\or.1em\or.07em\or.05em\fi\relax}

\def\sqdot{\mathbin{\varstyle{\raise\mathaxis\hbox{\setstyledim
       \kern\styledim 
       \vrule width1.2\styledim height.6\styledim depth.6\styledim
       \kern\styledim}}}}

$f\sqdot g, f\cdot g, \scriptstyle f\sqdot g, f\cdot g$

\bye
```

Answer (score 3):

Unicode-math fonts typically include the character `\smblksquare`. If you have loaded such font then you can type:

```
$a\mathbin\smblksquare b$
```

or define

```
\def\smallsquare{\mathbin\smblksquare}
```

The result (when `latinmodern-math.otf` is loaded) looks like this:

[image: small square]