# Is there that kind of symbol?

Tags: symbols

Is there a way to use that kind of symbol?

[image]

Comment: This is `\drsh` from `mathabx` or `\Rdsh` from `fdsymbol` or `stix`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use arrows from `mathabx`, but not the whole package that changes all math symbols in a way that could not be desirable. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273044/4427 for part of the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11.5> mathb10
  <11.5-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ulsh}{3}{mathb}{"E8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ursh}{3}{mathb}{"E9}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\dlsh}{3}{mathb}{"EA}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\drsh}{3}{mathb}{"EB}

\begin{document}

$a\drsh b$

$a\dlsh b$

$a\ursh b$

$a\ulsh b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a typo in `DeclareFontShape`: `mathbb12` should be replaced with `mathb12`, as [spotted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273034/square-version-of-cdot-small-black-square/273044#comment907515_273044) in the quoted answer.

Comment: @AndreyPopov Fixed, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}

$A \drsh B$

\end{document}
```

[image]