# Typesetting d'Alembertian symbol

Tags: symbols, typography

I've seen that usually, the d'Alembertian is written using the command `\Box`, however, this displays a square with all sides identical. I would like to write it in this other way:

[image]

in which, the right and below sides are bolder, so that resembles more to the Laplacian symbol.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! \square is indeed a better option since the scaling is better to the \Box, however, it still presents no difference in the strokes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Build a square with thicker lines the same size of `\square`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dalembertian}{\mathop{\mathpalette\dalembertian@\relax}}
\newcommand{\dalembertian@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\square$}%
  \dimen0=\fontdimen8
    \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
    \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
    \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi3
  \makebox[\wd\z@]{%
    \hbox to \ht\z@{%
      \vrule width \dimen0
      \kern-\dimen0
      \vbox to \ht\z@{
        \hrule height \dimen0 width \ht\z@
        \vss
        \hrule height 2\dimen0
      }%
      \kern-2.5\dimen0
      \vrule width 2.5\dimen0
    }%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\dalembertian = \mathop{{}\Delta}-\partial_0^2$

$\scriptstyle\dalembertian = \mathop{{}\Delta}-\partial_0^2$

$\scriptscriptstyle\dalembertian = \mathop{{}\Delta}-\partial_0^2$

{\Large$\dalembertian = \mathop{{}\Delta}-\partial_0^2$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

To increase the boarder on two sides, you could use the `\ding{113}` symbol from `pifont`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\text{\ding{113}}  \Delta$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is close to what I'm looking for, but strokes are maybe too thick.

Comment: @Janstillerion Some other package define similar symbols. For an overview have a look at http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Answer (score 8):

Just uses `\rule`s.  Then, `\scalerel` to make it match the height of `\Delta`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\dAlaux{%
  \Shortstack{\rule{12pt}{.6pt}\\
    \rule{.6pt}{10pt}\kern10pt\rule{1.4pt}{10pt}\\
    \rule{12pt}{1.4pt}}%
}
\newcommand\dAl{%
  \setstackgap{S}{0pt}%
  \setstackEOL{\\}%
  \scalerel*{\kern1pt\dAlaux\kern1pt}{\Delta}%
}
\begin{document}
$\dAl = \Delta - \partial_0^2,\quad \phi\dAl\phi e^{\phi\dAl\phi}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

A slightly thicker version, by adjusting the `\rule` dimensions...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\dAlaux{%
  \Shortstack{\rule{11pt}{.7pt}\\
    \rule{.7pt}{9pt}\kern9pt\rule{1.3pt}{9pt}\\
    \rule{11pt}{1.35pt}}%
}
\newcommand\dAl{%
  \setstackgap{S}{0pt}%
  \setstackEOL{\\}%
  \scalerel*{\kern1pt\dAlaux\kern1pt}{\Delta}%
}
\begin{document}
$\dAl = \Delta - \partial_0^2,\quad \phi\dAl\phi e^{\phi\dAl\phi}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version using `scalebox` and overlapping three copies of `\square` so that the thickness can be tweaked. The thickness can be changed by increasing or reducing the second argument to `\add@dalemb`.

For instance, with `03` and `06`:

> [image]

and with `05` and `10`:

> [image]

Thicker than this, another `\add@dalemb` would be needed to avoid white spaces between the `\square`s.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\dalemb{\mathpalette\inner@dalemb{}}
\def\inner@dalemb#1{%
  \add@dalemb#1{03}%
  \add@dalemb#1{06}%
  \square
}
\def\add@dalemb#1#2{%
  \sbox0{\scalebox{1.#2}{$#1\square$}}%
  \rlap{\lower0.#2\ht0\box0}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[ \Delta\dalemb \]
\[ \partial^{\Delta\dalemb} \]
\[ \partial^{\partial^{\Delta\dalemb}} \]

\end{document}
```